# sphinx-apidoc generating .rst files with wrong paths

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have the following structure of Sphinx directory:

```
top-directory
|
|--docs
|  |
|  |-conf.py
|  |-index.rst
|
|
|--first-dir
   |
   |- __init__.py
   |- script1.py
   |- script2.py
|
|--second-dir
   |
   |- __init__.py
   |- script3.py
   |- script4.py
```

In conf.py I added the following code:

```
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('../first-dir'))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('../second-dir'))
```

After running

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -e -o . ../
```

Sphinx generates a bunch of .rst files with names first-dir.script1.rst, first-dir.script2.rst and so on. The content of each .rst file follows this pattern:

```
.. automodule:: first-dir.script1
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

I added first-dir.script1 to index.rst,but after running make html in the doc directory, I get only empty pages.However, when I change the contents of first-dir.script1.rst to:

```
.. automodule:: script1
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

everything works fine and first-dir.script1 is populated with modules from script1. I assume I am doing something wrong since the whole point of Sphinx is to automatically generate .rst files, but I am not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Minor distinction: the point of sphinx-apidoc is to generate .rst files, whereas the point of Sphinx is to generate HTML, PDF, ePub, and other formats from .rst files. Anyway, first make a subdirectory `mypackage` under `top-directory`, put your two modules into `mypackage`, then try `sphinx-apidoc -F -a -f -e -o . ../my-package`.

Comment: I think it should work if you use `sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('..'))`. From the directory where conf.py is, you need to go up one level so that `top-directory` is in `sys.path`.